# Is CGAL compatible with the Clang compiler on OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, clang, cgal

Ever since switching to std=c++11 mode (or gnu++11, which seems slightly more stable), CGAL has been exceptionally crash-prone for me on OSX (there might have been more changes made at the same time; it was very chaotic).

We are building with Clang.  This [very dated FAQ entry](http://www.cgal.org/FAQ.html#mac_optimization_bug) suggests that the standard OSX compiler used to have issues with CGAL.

> The default compiler on Mac OS X is g++ 4.0 (at least on Tiger and
>   Leopard). It has some bugs that are unfortunately encountered by some
>   programs using CGAL when optimizing. We recommend that you use a more
>   recent version of g++, such as g++ 4.2, which you can get by upgrading
>   to the latest XCode, or using Fink.

Is this still relevant?

About to try rebuilding CGAL (and header including libraries) without optimizations, but I'd like to know what the official support is for Clang on OSX.

**Update**

It's looking like user error.  A number of APPLE #ifdefs were added during the C++11 upgrade (for unclear reasons), and removing them seems to be fixing many of the crashes.

Comment: Mileage may vary, but recent clang is generally ahead of g++ 4.8.2.. that said i haven't used cgal since '05 and it was a world of hurt back then to nestle the thing into visual studio. ( linux was sooo much easier )l.   that said if you are looking for offical support you are on the wrong site. Only CGAL's site will list its official support.

Comment: That FAQ entry is not relevant to recent versions of OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to CGAL's website, CLANG is supported.

http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/installation.html#seccompilers